# Using AWS API in order to invoke Lambda functions Asynchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have been researching AWS Documentation on how to invoke lambda functions, and I've come across different ways to do that. Mainly, Lambda invocation is done by calling `Invoke()` function which can be used to invoke lambda functions synchronously or asynchronously.

Currently I am invoking my Lambda functions via HTTP Request (as REST API), but, HTTP Request times out after 30 seconds, while asynchronous calls as far as I know times out after 15min.

What are the advantages, besides time that I have already mentioned, of asynchronous lambda invocation compared to invoking lambda with HTTP Request. Also, what are best (recommended) ways to invoke lambdas in production? On AWS docs (SDK for Go - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#InvokeAsyncInput) I see that `InvokeAsyncInput` and `InvokeAsyncOutput` have been depricated. So I am wondering how async implementation would actually look like.

Answer (score 4):

Lambda really is about event-driven-computing. This means Lambda always gets triggered in response to an **event**. This event can originate from a wide [range of AWS Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html?shortFooter=true) as well as the AWS CLI and SDK.

All of these events invoke the Lambda function and pass some kind of information in the form of an `event` and `context` object. How this event looks like depends on the service that triggered lambda. You can find more information about the context in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html?shortFooter=true).

There is no real "best" way to invoke Lambda - this mostly depends on your use case - if you're building a webservice, let API Gateway invoke Lambda for you. If you want to process new files on S3 - let S3 trigger Lambda. If you're just testing the Lambda function you can invoke it via the CLI. If you have custom software that needs to trigger a Lambda function you can use the SDK. If you want to run Lambda on a schedule, configure CloudWatch events...

Please provide more information about your use case if you require a more detailed evaluation of the available options - right now this is very broad.

Comment: I would like to allow both synchronous and asynchronous invocations. For example, I would like for my Lambda to be invoked as Rest API if needed, or to be invoked asynchronously with some JSON Payload. In order to achieve that, do I need to create `InvokeInput` object and pass it to `Invoke()` function?

Comment: You should probably use API Gateway in front of the Lambdas. For async requests (where the request is queued and immediately acknowledged), include an HTTP header X-Amz-Invocation-Type=Event.